# Setting up a externally facing server on Windows. How do i setup DNS/Nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

So i have a domain name that i would like to host from my static ip internet connection. I have windows server 2008 r2 installed, and dns setup. The dns server is currently behind a firewall, and i have the appropriate rules to allow traffic to reach it.

My question is, what entries do i need to create in the DNS so that i can have some nameservers to use at my domain registrar, so that the domain correctly points to the server?

I know that most domains have nameservers like ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com, etc. What would i point those to in my DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a NS record that lists the hostname of your server (this defines it as a DNS name server) and you need an A record that matches that hostname to your external IP address. You then need to tell your domain registar to point to this hostname for DNS. That will get you started and then you're free to create other DNS records on your server as you wish.

Comment: what if i already have an A record for the hostname that points to an internal IP? do i change this to point to the external IP?

Comment: The external world can not reach your internal IP addresses - if you need external access to a server, then yes, the A record needs to point to your external IP.

Comment: Don't forget about reverse DNS. Get your ISP to create a record for your public IP that also points to the domain you set up.